# Centralizer of $\sigma\in S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let  $\sigma\in S_n$ . Describe the centralizer of $\sigma$.

Thought: If I conjugate $\sigma$, then $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau=\sigma.$ This means that $\tau$ is a power of $\sigma,$ and $<\sigma>\subseteq C_{S_n}(\sigma).$ What should I do after? I guess I just want to know what are the elements that commute with $\sigma$.

Comment: Your "this means that..." is not correct in general. It is true that all powers of $\sigma$ commute with $\sigma$, but there might be other elements too.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formula for what happens to a cycle when it is conjugated by some permutation?